# Linq to objects not "persisting" changes

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

I am using linq to select a bunch of objects by Id through a facade object. This facade has a function `GetObjectById(string id)` which returns a MyObject. I select a bunch of object in one query based on a list of ids:

```
IEnumerable<MyObject> objects = 
   from id in ids   
   select facade.GetObjectById(id);
```

Then later I set some value on my objects like so:

```
foreach(MyObject object in objects)
{
  object.someValue = "banaan";
}
```

Later when I inspect the objects IEnumerable, `someValue` is not set to "banaan".

It looks like it has something to do with the deferred execution of linq because when I put `.ToList()` behind the first query I *does* work. However, I thought I should be able to do something like this. What am I doing wrong here? Or is my understanding of how you should use linq wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it is the problem of deferred execution. If the query is executed again it will again call your facade method during and if the facade method loads data from somewhere (= create new instances) your former changes are lost. Your `foreach` is first execution and inspection outside of the first `foreach` is second execution.

You must call `ToList` if you want to operate on the same instances in such scenario.

Answer (score 1):

When you inspect the objects the second time, do you re-evaluate the `objects` enumerable? Because that would make it call facade.GetObjectById(id) again.

Try to materialize the enumerable instead. Something like this:

```
IEnumerable<MyObject> objects = 
    (from id in ids 
     select facade.GetObjectById(id)).ToArray();
```

Comment: But doesn't that make a copy of my list? I have a few functions like that, that call each other. I.e. GetObjectsById(IEnumerable<string> ids) calls GetObjectById. It would be copied everytime and would break the deferred execution benifits right? I thought deferred execution would not mean: repeated every time execution.

Comment: Without the ToArray/ToList you won't actually have any list at all, just a way of recreating that enumeration. You only really benefit from deferred execution when you iterate at most one time over the collection.

Comment: BTW, If you want to really understand LINQ and what's going on behind the scenes, I recommend reading Jon Skeets Edulinq series of blog posts (now available in ebook-format): http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/03/18/edulinq-the-e-book.aspx

Comment: The problem I have in my mind is my perception of the IEnumerable interface. I thought I could just call my function GetObjects(ids). Iterate over the result and set some values. Then pass on that IEnumerable. If the GetObjects(ids) function was implemented like in my question, it wouldn't work. I guess the IEnumerable interface is really a read only thing. (Although not always...)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're running a SQL server somewhere from which the data comes from?

The query will remain in LINQ to SQL space until, as suggested in both previous answers, you call ToList() or ToArray() or similar. Only then does it actually become LINQ to Object, and is the data instantiated and will it persist in your program's memory space.

In this way, after your changes to your list, you can execute the same query again and get a different list which does not have your changes in it.

Maybe a better explanation is the following:

```
(from id in ids select facade.GetObjectById(id)).Where(o=>string.IsNullOrEmpty(o.Name))
```

This will give an error because there is no translation from string.IsNullOrEmpty to SQL.

```
(from id in ids select facade.GetObjectById(id)).ToList().Where(o=>string.IsNullOrEmpty(o.Name))
```

This will not give an error, because after the ToList() you are in object space.

Comment: I am not using SQL server, just objects (coming from a WCF service).